# How do I change this code from dropdown menu to radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

It displays a drop down and I need it to display radio buttons instead.
Im playing around with a workaround, but it´s not really clean.

What does I have to change on the following code to have radio buttons instead of a dropdown menu

Thanks for any help,

Here is the workaround:
http://jsfiddle.net/a31p2371/16/

```js
<script>

  Shopify.queryParams = {};
  if (location.search.length) {
    for (var aKeyValue, i = 0, aCouples = location.search.substr(1).split('&'); i < aCouples.length; i++) {
      aKeyValue = aCouples[i].split('=');
      if (aKeyValue.length > 1) {
        Shopify.queryParams[decodeURIComponent(aKeyValue[0])] = decodeURIComponent(aKeyValue[1]);
      }
    }
  }
  jQuery('.coll-picker').change(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).val()) {
      location.href = '/collections/' + jQuery(this).val();
    }
    else {
      location.href = '/collections/all';
    }
  });
  var collFilters = jQuery('.coll-filter');
  collFilters.change(function() {
    delete Shopify.queryParams.page;
    var newTags = [];
    collFilters.each(function() {
      if (jQuery(this).val()) {
        newTags.push(jQuery(this).val());
      }
    });
    {% if collection.handle %}
    var newURL = '/collections/{{ collection.handle }}';
    if (newTags.length) {
      newURL += '/' + newTags.join('+');
    }
    var search = jQuery.param(Shopify.queryParams);
    if (search.length) {
      newURL += '?' + search;
    }
    location.href = newURL;
    {% else %}
    if (newTags.length) {
      Shopify.queryParams.constraint = newTags.join('+');
    }
    else {
      delete Shopify.queryParams.constraint;
    }
    location.search = jQuery.param(Shopify.queryParams);
    {% endif %}
  });
</script>
```

```html
<ul class="clearfix filters">
  <li class="clearfix filter">
    {% assign tags = 'Kaschiert, Chromokarton, Recyclingkarton, Kunststoff' | split: ',' %}
    <label>Material</label>
    <select class="coll-filter">
      <option value="">All</option>
      {% for t in tags %}
      {% assign tag = t | strip %}
      {% if current_tags contains tag %}
      <option value="{{ tag | handle }}" selected>{{ tag }}</option>
      {% elsif collection.all_tags contains tag %}
      <option value="{{ tag | handle }}">{{ tag }}</option>
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </li>
 
</ul>
```

Comment: Code from: https://docs.shopify.com/support/your-store/collections/filtering-a-collection-with-multiple-tag-drop-down

Answer (score 1):

Change html to this

```
  <ul class="clearfix filters">
      <li class="clearfix filter">
        {% assign tags = 'Kaschiert, Chromokarton, Recyclingkarton, Kunststoff' | split: ',' %}


          <input type="radio" name="coll-filter" value="">All>
          {% for t in tags %}
          {% assign tag = t | strip %}
          {% if current_tags contains tag %}
          <input type="radio" name="coll-filter" value="{{ tag | handle }}" selected>{{ tag }}
          {% elsif collection.all_tags contains tag %}
          <input type="radio" name="coll-filter" value="{{ tag | handle }}">{{ tag }}
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
      </li>

    </ul>
```

change this `collFilters.change(function() {` to this  `collFilters.click(function() {`